# HTML elements getting dislocated when shown in print preview

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have developed html page ..looks good on IE
But when Shown for print prievew all the html elements gets disloacated ,orientation gets missed out.

Why is that so ..any help.

Following is sample code

```
<body onload="JavaScript:somefunction();">

<header> 

    <div id="headerIamge">               
       <img src="Images\\_logo.png" />                   
          </div>
     </header>

          <div id="sectionbody">
          <div id="buttonPanel">

              </div>
             </div>

              <div id="sectionheader">

                  <div id="title"></div>

              </div>
            <div id="parentAreaContent">

            </div>
         <table>
             <colgroup>
                 <col width="1200px" />
                 <col width ="5px" />
             </colgroup>
             <tr>
                 <td>
          <div id="navigation">

            <nav id="assetNavTargets">
                <ul>

                </ul>

            </nav>
                          </div>
          <div id ="deviceImage"></div>

               </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     <br />
            <div id="MainContentArea"></div>
             </div>     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Css

```
  #divbox{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color: #E6EAEC;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;

}
```

css elements uses px and for some elemnst I have used % for giving sizes.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: We need your html and css to help you with that.

Comment: Most likely to do with the mix of `%` and `px`, as the size of an A4 page is constant, and usually much smaller than a normal webpage. If possible, use Javascript to convert your `%` values to `px`.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `%` or `px`, otherwise print preview will not be able to compensate for the size of a printable sheet. 
Though it isn't easy, I'd probably use Javascript to convert:

```
function xPercentToPixels(percentage) {
    return ((document.body.clientWidth / 100) * percentage) + "px";
}

function yPercentToPixels(percentage) {
    return ((document.body.clientHeight / 100) * percentage) + "px";
}
```

You can then change all of the `%` values to `px`, and it should work comparitively better.